# android sorting an array

Tags: java, android, sorting

i'm trying to sort my array but from some reason i got the following error in my compareTo function:

```
Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int
```

my code:

```
private void sortFriendList()
{
    Arrays.sort(friendsList, new Comparator<FacebookUser>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(FacebookUser lhs, FacebookUser rhs) {                
            ChatMessage[] firstChatMessages = app.getDatabaseManager().getChatMessages(lhs.getId());
            ChatMessage[] lastChatMessages = app.getDatabaseManager().getChatMessages(rhs.getId());
            int firstLastMessageTime = (int) firstChatMessages[firstChatMessages.length-1].getTime();
            int lastLastMessageTime = (int) lastChatMessages[firstChatMessages.length-1].getTime();
            return firstLastMessageTime.compareTo(lastLastMessageTime);
        }
    });     
 }
```

the code supposed to sort an array buy time stored in long type (which i've cast to int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't cast `long` to `int` to avoid loss of precision. Rather box it to `Long`

```
long firstLastMessageTime = //...
long lastLastMessageTime = //...
return Long.valueOf(firstLastMessageTime).compareTo(Long.valueOf(lastLastMessageTime));
```

Comment: Isn't it a bit overkill to create two objects instead of two simple ifs?

Answer (score 3):

The `compareTo`method only works on objects. An primitive `int` is no object. You have to manually compare the int values and return either negative, zero or positive value, if this values is less, equal or greater than the other value.

Using the Integer wrapper class for that is just wasting resources.

This morning I'm more willing to provide some code:

```
long firstLastMessageTime = ...
long lastLastMessageTime = ...
if (firstLastMessageTime < lastLastMessageTime) {
    return -1;
}
if (firstLastMessageTime > lastLastMessageTime) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
```

In some cases you could do firstLastMessageTime minus lastLastMessageTime, but that maybe lead to errors if you handle with negative values or if the difference can be bigger than a 32bit int value. So to be 100% sure, just use the above method all the time.

---

Additional comment:

Is the value really a int value? Usually the time is defined as the milliseconds since 1.1.1970 in Java, which as datatype is long.

Comment: its a long, but i need to return an int doesn't i ?

Comment: Read the definition of the compareTo method you implement and it should be clear what you have to return. And yes you have to return an int value.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
        return Integer.valueof(firstLastMessageTime).compareTo(lastLastMessageTime);
```

Before invoking comapreTo method you have to wrap `int` into `Integer` object.

Comment: A little explanation of what you did may help OP (and others) even more.

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot invoke compareTo on primitive types, You should use their wrapper classes. **Integer** rather than **int**